# react with ts - check if props empty inside map view.tsx

Tags: reactjs

The props -

```
interface Props {
  readonly historicPrices: IHistoricPrices[] | null;
  readonly historicPricesChangeHandler: (value: IHistoricPrices[] | null) => void;
}
```

The view.tsx code -

```
          <div className={classes['innerContainer']}>
            {props.historicPrices?.map((price, idx) => {
              return (
                <li className={classes['innerContainer__text']} key={idx}>
                  {t(`historicPrices.currency.${currency}`)}
                  {price.price}
                  {t('historicPrices.date')}
                  {price.createdAt}
                </li>
              )
            })}
          </div>
```

How can i display a message if the array is returning nothing

Comment: Since you are using map(), the only time it will return an empty array is when the array itself is empty. You can check for that right? Correct me if I am wrong

Comment: @TusharShahi I don't know the syntax for the check, new to react.
but yeah it make sense to check for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `&&`. With [`&&`](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html#inline-if-with-logical--operator) operator, second expression is only run when first is true.

```
     {props.historicPrices.length === 0 && <p>Alert</p> }
```

If you conditionally want to show one or the other you can use `?` conditional operator:

```
     {props.historicPrices.length === 0 ? <p>Alert</p> : props.historicPrices?.map((price, idx) => {
              return (
                <li className={classes['innerContainer__text']} key={idx}>
                  {t(`historicPrices.currency.${currency}`)}
                  {price.price}
                  {t('historicPrices.date')}
                  {price.createdAt}
                </li>
              )
            })}
```

Above code returns `<p>`, when length is 0, otherwise the map function is run and that will be rendered.

Comment: How to display the else?

Comment: @Brgbegnefneg with || operator. Or with [cond ? a : b](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html#inline-if-else-with-conditional-operator)

Answer (score 0):

you should always do a state value with a default value.

```
const [array, setArray] = useState([]);
```

for the undefined properties of an object, you have two options in this case:

```
const value = prop.value ? prop.value : "some default value";
```

or

```
tableSelected?.id
```

Pick your posion